# Notification light in silent mode on Lollipop

Tags: notifications, 5.0-lollipop

With Android 4.4 on my Nexus 5, when I set the notification volume to 0, the notification LED would still pulse when receiving a notififaction. This is the setting I usually want.
Now, with 5.0, I cannot find a way to keep the phone completely silent but still receive notifications via the LED.

Did I overlook a setting, or did Google really mess up that badly?

Comment: There's an issue on the [Android bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79445) for this behavior. Google have not yet commented on it, from what I can see. It seems like the intention was perhaps that people would start using Priority mode instead, as a more "flexible" version of silent mode, but I'm not sure if that's actually the case or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found so far is purchasing the popular app "Light Flow" for currently $2.49 and in this app activate "Show LED in priority mode". Then just set the phone to priority mode and you have pretty much the same behavior as in pre-Lollipop. Still annoying, though, to have to use an extra app for this. There might be free app alternatives, but I already wasted too much time for this and didn't search for that.