# Allow LED flashing for notification while on silent mode (interruptions: none)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-versions, 5.1-lollipop

I use my phone in school. If I use priority mode or none mode, I can't see the notifications by front LED of my phone, which I could with Android KitKat 4.4. It was easy in school, there was no sound but I didn't had to check my phone every 5 sec to see if I had a message. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Don't know what's wrong with your version, but on my device, if I select none, the notification light works and I can also see the notifications on the lockscreen. I use android 5.0, what version do you have?

Comment: Version 5.0.2. I don't know if it's a difference..

Comment: I also have version 5.0.2, sorry. Have you set the preference in the system settings, that every notification is shown on the lockscreen? You can set this in the notification manager in the settings

Comment: It's shown in lockscreen if I touch the button I can see my notification.. but the lockscreen doesn't light up and so doesn't my notification light..

Comment: I asked the same question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88835/notification-light-in-silent-mode-on-lollipop
If nothing has changed yet, there isn't a really satisfying answer and only and workaround.

Comment: I removed the statement regarding "alarm doesn't ring on silent mode" because it's not really related to the problem, and because Android already warns about it. Alarm only works on priority and all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CyanogenMod (mine is CM12), there's a setting for this. Look under "Display & lights", and find "Ambient display".

Hope it helps

[image: Be sure to set your preference like this]
<sup>Be sure to set your preference like this (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using custom ROM like CyanogenMod? I couldn't find this feature on Nexus 5, stock Lollipop 5.1 (and the menu is "Display" only, not "Display & lights" here).

Comment: Yes I have cyanogenmod. Try to find the preference with the search.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why your notification light plainly does not work. Try using one of the LED customization tools such as Xposed, change the settings and see if it works after that.
http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.mohammadag.xposedledcontrol